# I can't seem to concatenate an API URL with a variable

Tags: javascript, async-await, concatenation, fetch-api

I am fetching an exchange rates API. The API looks like this: `https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/Your-Api-Key/latest/AMD`, where "Your-API-Key" is my personal key. If the API URL ends with USD or AMD, the API recognises the base currency as USD or AMD and then gives the exchange rate in other currencies, including the base currency.

For example:

HTML:

```html
<select name="BaseCurrency" id="BaseCurrency">
    <option value="NGN">NGN</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
async function fetchCurrencyData() {
    let baseCurrencyValue = document.getElementById("BaseCurrency").value;
    console.log(baseCurrencyValue) // logs selected HTML option value, say "NGN" or "USD", based on user selection.

    let result = await fetch(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/My-Api-Key/latest/${baseCurrencyValue}`);
    let record = await result.json();
    console.log("Hey " + JSON.stringify(record.conversion_rates.baseCurrencyValue)); //This logs "Hey undefined" but when I replace baseCurrencyValue with an actual currency code, like USD, it prints out the correct rate"
```

What can I do to make sure that concatenating the variable "baseCurrencyValue" at the end of the API, will work? Because I need to allow the user's choice to be the base currency

I have also tried concatenating with the plus sign:

```js
let result = await fetch("https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/My-Api-Key/latest/" + baseCurrencyValue);
```

But it isn't working either.

Comment: Are you sure 'baseCurrencyValue' is actually an string? Also you could try to print 'record' value, as it is possible that it exists but maybe it doesn't have any 'conversion_rates' property (or 'baseCurrencyValue').

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, it does have conversion_rates property. Then it has the currency code properties. Below is a part of it

{
 "time_last_update_utc":"Sun, 13 Feb 2022 00:00:02 +0000",
 "time_next_update_unix":1644796802,
 "time_next_update_utc":"Mon, 14 Feb 2022 00:00:02 +0000",
 "base_code":"USD",
 "conversion_rates":{
  "USD":1,
  "AED":3.6725,
  }

So I want baseCurrencyValue to be the value of the HTML <select> tag, then it will be passed to the API string

Answer (score 0):

You ensure that it will work by controlling what inputs you accept. Also I noticed that there is a CORS issue with this API, which can be fixed with corsAnywhere. Ideally you should be calling external APIs on your backend not your frontend.

```html
<select name="BaseCurrency" id="base-currency">
    <option value="NGN">NGN</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select>

<button onclick="fetchCurrencyData()">click</button>

<script>
    async function fetchCurrencyData() {
        const baseCurrencyValue = document.getElementById('base-currency').value;

        const result = await fetch(
            `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/APIKEYHERE/latest/${baseCurrencyValue}`
        );
        const { conversion_rates } = await result.json();

        console.log(conversion_rates);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you must allow yourself access https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: also you just gave everyone your api token, delete your comment @EmmanuelAnietieSamuel

Comment: Thanks, @mstephen19. I thought it was the sample link. I do appreciate it.